# Page/Screen Jump

Tags: principle-app

Was wondering if anyone figured out a way to do a page/screen jump on Principle.

If you're not familiar with a page jump, it works the same way like a website when you click a link and the page jumps down or up to a specific area on that same page the link was referencing to. I'm trying to manipulate that same action in my prototype where a user can tap on a link at the top of the page, and it jumps them down to a lower part of that screen.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to do. All you need is your full height content.

[image]